# How to determine the patch level of SAP GUI from a dump?

Tags: sap-gui

I have a crash dump of SAP GUI (saplogon.exe) and would like to know which Patch Level is has. How can I get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the Patch Level in SAP Logon's system menu / About SAP Logon. Looking at different SAP GUI versions, you'll find that the patch level is encoded in the third part of the version number:

SAP GUI 7.30, Patch Level 8:

[image: SAP 7.30, Patch Level 8]

SAP GUI 7.40, Patch Level 3:

[image: SAP 7.40, Patch Level 3]

Knowing this makes it almost trivial to get the patch level from the dump:

```
0:011> lm vm saplogon
start    end        module name
01190000 0132a000   saplogon   (deferred)             
    ...
    Image name: saplogon.exe
    ...
    ProductName:      SAP GUI for Windows
    InternalName:     SAP Logon
    OriginalFilename: saplogon.exe
    ProductVersion:   730 Final Release
    FileVersion:      7300.3.8.1084
    ...
0:011> * --------------------^
```